# Change items in navigation bar on device rotation

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have custom `UIBarButton` items added to `UINavigationBar` as `rightbarbuttonitems`. I add two more items in `UIBarButton` when device goes to `landscape mode`. I am getting `rotation` call and I am correctly removing items from `UIBarbuttons` array based on device orientation, but my navigationbar item set never gets updates.

If i start with portrait mode, it shows what it suppose to. When I rotate to `landscape` new items are not added to `navigation bar` and vice versa extra item won't go when device go to portrait.

I am not sure how I can change navigationbaritems on device rotation. Per me I am doing all things correct.

```
-(void)setUpOnRotation:(BOOL)toPortrait{

_searchMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0, 0, 110, 20)];
_searchMessage.numberOfLines = 2;
_searchMessage.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
_searchMessage.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];
_searchMessage.text = @"";

_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, 130, 25)];
_searchBar.delegate = self;
_searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [BarButtons doneButtonWithTarget:self action:@selector(cancel)];
UIBarButtonItem *searchActivityItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_searchMessage];
UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_searchBar];
UIBarButtonItem *in = [BarButtons nativeButtonNamed:@"In"
                                                  title:@"In"
                                                  target:self
                                                  action:@selector(In)];
UIBarButtonItem *out = [BarButtons nativeButtonNamed:@"Out"
                                                  title:@"Out"
                                                  target:self
                                                  action:@selector(Out)];


NSMutableArray *itemsSet;
itemsSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:in,
            out,
            searchItem,
            searchActivityItem,
            doneButton, nil];
if (toPortrait) {
    if ([itemsSet containsObject:searchItem] || [itemsSet containsObject:searchActivityItem]) {
        [itemsSet removeObject:searchActivityItem];
        [itemsSet removeObject:searchItem];
    }
 }


[_searchBar release];
[searchItem release];
[_searchActivity release];
[_searchMessage release];
[searchActivityView release];


self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = itemsSet;
}


- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
     [self setUpOnRotation:UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)];
}   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
  [self setUpOnRotation:UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)];}
```

Note: `setUpOnRotaion` method is called from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and `viewWillAppear` with `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.intefaceOrientation)` and it does give me correct result. I have debugged.

Comment: It should work... Can you include the code from willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation?

Comment: what is BarButtons ?

Comment: @AKG Are you saying the code works for you now or not?

Comment: No, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation change cehck for orientation

```
    if([uidevice orientaiton]statusbarorientation]){
    self.naviogationite.rightbarbuttonitems =  @[btn1,btn2,btn3];
    }
    else{
    self.naviogationite.rightbarbuttonitems =  @[abtn1,abtn2,abnt3];
    }
    u can do like this

can u do like this

NSMutableArray *itemsSet;

if(!toPortrait){
itemsSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:in,
            out,
            searchItem,
            searchActivityItem,
            doneButton, nil];
}
if (toPortrait) {
  itemsSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:in,
            out,
            doneButton, nil];
}
```

Comment: @AKG the answer i pasted here is working fine for me.I tried to run in my simulator its working fine.Please check once with ur xcode.Chek all the orientations is selected in ur general project settings. http://pastie.org/9759820

Comment: @AKG self.orientation is not working in iOS 8 u could do this   [self setUpOnRotation:UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])];

Comment: did u try the code in pastie? i tried in my simulator.i cannot help anymore because problem is not in this code and problem is not even in ur code